# No Ram Reduction with Pandas Dataframe to Sqlite DB

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I couldn't find anything on this. Why does creating a sqlite database with a pandas data frame and then deleting the dataframe not reduce my ram usage? I'm using a combination of pandas, sqlite, and sqlalchemy

```
con = create_engine('sqlite:///k.db')
df.to_sql('df', con, if_exists='replace', 
                     #index=False, 
                     #index_label=None, 
                     #schema=None, 
                     chunksize=2000#,
                     #dtype=None
                    )
del df
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python del not freeing all the memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35121659/python-del-not-freeing-all-the-memory)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that in this context, a sqlite database is formed in ram, so no gain in ram will be achieved.